# AnyLogic Road Library Lane Selection

Tags: anylogic

I have a single-lane road expanding into a multi-lane road with a stop line at the end of it. As the car moves from the single-lane section to the multi-lane section it selects the lane seemingly randomly. However, this causes the multi-lane section to back up much quicker than what would happen in real life as one lane will fill up while the other is still empty.

Is there a way to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following approach in this type of situations:

- define a function called fnSelectLane(car)
- manually assign the lane by conditions

You can also check how many cars are in each lane with this function `int nCarsOnLane(boolean isOnForwardSide, int laneIndex)`.
Long story short, you can manually assign the lanes, if you don't like the default setup.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This looks much simpler than the approach I ended up using with external lists. Will give it a go

Comment: Great! Please feel free to upvote and accept as answer:)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not find the car.lane property/variable to set.

Comment: lane is a variable that I have created of type int. At the start of that multi-lane road, I put carEnter block, there de-select random lane option and set it to car.lane programmatically.